# Правильно расставить знаки препинания

Tags: запятые

Для определения стоимости реализации проекта "Строительство объекта" по адресу: Краснодарский край, г. Краснодар" - необходимы следующие данные:
- предоставить проект;
- и т.д.

Comment: Я позволил себе восстановить предполагаемыое форматирование. В строчку двоеточие с тире смотрятся просто дико.

Answer (score 0):

> Для определения стоимости реализации проекта «Строительство объекта по адресу: Краснодарский край, г. Краснодар» необходимы следующие данные: предоставить проект,

Если выбросить название, получается безличное простое предложение, после слова данные (а именно) — двоеточие, дальше перечисление через запятую.
Содержание не правлю, но после слова «данные» хорошо бы употребить существительное.

Answer (score 0):

Для определения стоимости реализации проекта объекта "...", расположенного по адресу: ...,  необходимо предоставить:

1. элемент списка;
2. элемент списка;
3. элемент списка.

Слова *реализация проекта* можно заменить одним словом — *проектирование*.